# How many years does it take for 1 dollar to become 3 dollars at 5% interest compounded continuously?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, economics

(Round up to the next year.)

> a. How many years does it take for 1 to become 3 at $5\%$ interest
>   compounded continuously?
>
> b. How many years does it take for $\$1,000,000$ to become $\$3,000,000$ at
>   $5\%$ interest compounded continuously?

Can someone please walk me through/help me solve this? I'm in 8th grade, Algebra 1. Middle school.

I would appreciate If you just gave me the formula and explained how it works.

Comment: rule of 110 ?  if you don't get that look up rule of 69.3

Comment: $c\left(1+\frac{r}{n}\right)^{y\cdot n}$ where $c$ is the initial value ($3$), $r$ is the rate ($5\%)$, $n$ denotes how often the interest is calculted and $y$ the ammount of years. Is the equation which denotes compound interest. If you want it contnuously, you apply the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

One dollar, compounded continuously with an annual interest rate $r$, will become $e^{rt}$ dollars after $t$ years. Therefore, you need to solve the equation
$$e^{rt}=3$$
and the solution is about $t=21.9$ years.

Comment: This is not the right formula for continuous compounding

Comment: @Wojowu you probably have in mind exponential compounding. However, most banks do not use the exponential formula.

Comment: I don't know what exponential compounding is, and I don't know whether banks use it or not, but to my understand the term "continuous compounding" solely refers to compounding with the number of periods per year tending to infinity.

Comment: @Wojowu - that is correct, Wojowu, in theory, and indeed leads to the exponential formula, i.e. to the equation $e^{rt}=3$ to be solved with $r=0.05$, which produces the solution $t=21.9$. However, as I have already commented, in practical finance the other equation is used more frequently.

Comment: I'm confused by the objection and the explanation.  So far as I know that *is* the formula for continuous interest and don't understand why Wojowu says it isn't.  (After all $\lim (1+\frac rn)^{tn}=e^{rt}$).  But when uniquesolution says s/he's probably thinking of something else I don't see what that something else would be.

Comment: @fleablood, your confusion is understandable, but do note that the answer changed since its last version :). Ok, I think I will delete my answer now, as this is a good answer now.

Comment: Why would you delete it if the answer is *good* now?

Comment: All of these comments are quite confusing... Is @uniquesolution right or wrong???

Comment: @GraciousBean The answer is right now. If you have any further questions feel free to ask.